# Can't fix this error message on the console "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." React Js

Tags: reactjs

I'm new whit React. I have always the message on the browser that "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop".
I'm working with components and Bootstrap.

I tried in different ways to past the API key={values.id} on the card but something is wrong. Can somebody please help me?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


function Home() {

    const [fake, setFake] = useState([]);
    console.log(fake);
    useEffect(() => {
        fakestore();
    }, [])

    const fakestore = async () => {
        const response = await
            fetch('https://api.escuelajs.co/api/v1/products');

        const jsonData = await response.json();

        setFake(jsonData);
    }
    return (
        <>

        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row mt-5'>
                {fake.map((values) => {
                    return (
                        <>
                            
                            <div className='col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mt-5'>
                                <div className="card" key={values.id}>
                                    <img src={values.images} className="card-img-top w-100" alt={values.description} />
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        <h5  className="card-title">{values.title}</h5>
                                        <p className="card-text">{values.description}</p>
                                        <p className="card-text"><strong>€ {values.price.toFixed(2)}</strong></p>
                                        <button className="btn btn-primary">Add to Wishlist </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </>
                    )

                })}
            </div>
        </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

Thanks

Hope to fix the error message on the browser.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/5211833)

Comment: You just need to replace key attribute to the upper div `<div className="card" key={values.id}>` and this will fix your issue

Comment: What do you mean?? Replace with what? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @pacifica94 [said above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75519914/12252601), the "`key`" prop need to be placed in the outermost wrapper of element/component inside a `map()`. In other words, it's a direct element/component inside the `map()`.

Small notice here, `key` is a special prop that you can add in any component itself. In case that you want the wrapper is a React fragment (`<></>`), you also can add key like this:

```
<React.Fragment key={...}>
  // code here...
</React.Fragment>
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 2):

They key needs to attach to the highest parent within the map:

also, you have no need for a fragment here so I've removed it

```
            {fake.map((values) => (
              <div key={values.id} className='col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mt-5'>
                <div className='card'>
                  <img src={values.images} className='card-img-top w-100' alt={values.description} />
                  <div className='card-body'>
                    <h5 className='card-title'>{values.title}</h5>
                    <p className='card-text'>{values.description}</p>
                    <p className='card-text'>
                      <strong>€ {values.price.toFixed(2)}</strong>
                    </p>
                    <button className='btn btn-primary'>Add to Wishlist </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
```